# How can I automate "sudo chmod a+r /dev/usb/hiddev0" upon linux start?

Tags: linux, boot

I have a [footpedal](http://www.altoedge.com/pedals/vec-infinity-foot-pedals.html) and fortunately there is a software for using it under linux (see http://code.google.com/p/footpedal/). The author of that software already solved an issue for me (see issues there), but there is no option to ask simpler questions.

Unfortunately prior to use the software I have to change the device permission each time I start linux. How could I change that to be done automatically at startup?

Comment: That depends on your distribution. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new file under `/etc/udev/rules.d` that contains an appropriate udev rule for setting the permissions on the device.

Comment: That is the real answer to the real question.

Comment: Have a look at http://weininger.net/how-to-write-udev-rules-for-usb-devices.html - helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Historicaly there is a `/etc/rc.local` which is execute at the end of all other init scripts.
To put your script in rc5.d and rc3.d you need a script that will run with start as parameter.

Comment: This is the easiest best solution. +1

Comment: Technically, ir you're running from /etc/rc.*, you don't even need sudo, you're already root. You could remove it from the command

Answer (score 0):

Normally, that would be a script under the `/etc/rc*` hierarchy. The scripts under (for example) `/etc/rc5.d` (from memory) are for run level 3 which is the level most systems end up in.

You should look into `init` since this is the program that runs all those scripts. There's a useful article [here](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114107).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you probably have Vixie cron, which can run things on system reboot.  You can run `sudo` things here **if** you have the sudo entry marked as NOPASSWD

Run:
`crontab -e`
And it will open your crontab file in your editor (as set by `EDITOR` variable) and add the line

```
@reboot    sudo chmod a+r /dev/usb/hiddev0
```

and save it.  If you have a chance i'd reboot just to test it.

`crontab -e` will probably run in vi, if you don't know how to run vi, maybe try kate or gedit

```
EDITOR=kate crontab -e
```

or

```
EDITOR=gedit crontab -e
```